# GPU Compute Capability 3.0 but the minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, anaconda, gpu

I tried to install tensorflow-gpu. When I checked the installation using this command

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

The result was

```
 Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: Quadro K5100M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 3.0) with Cuda compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5. => False
```

1. Operating System = Windows 10
2. GPU type: Nvidia Quadro k5100m
3. GPU driver version = 426.78
4. python = 3.7.7
5. Cuda Toolkit = 10.1
6. cuDNN = 7.6.5
7. TensorRT = 6.0
8. tensorflow-gpu = 2.1.0

**How can I solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

The [Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#hardware_requirements) states

> Only the NVIDIA® GPU card with CUDA® Compute Capability 3.5 or higher
> are supported for Tensorflow-GPU.

As the Error Message suggests, your `Graphics Card (Nvidia Quadro k5100m)` has `Compute Capability` `3.0` and the Minimum Version supported is 3.5.

**Solution** is that you may have to upgrade your Graphics Card to any of [these GPUs](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) supported by Tensorflow.

Mentioning the List of `Quadro GPUs` supported by `Tensorflow` below for your reference:

[image]

Comment: My graphic card, GeForce 765m, is in your mentioned support list and has cc 3, but I give the same error. Shall I buy a new card to use GPU for TensorFlow? Or is there a solution?